# ListView bad performance using Pixate

Tags: android, css, pixate

I'm using pixate and all works fine but for ListView the scrolling is not fluent. If I remove the `PixateFreestyle.init(this);` the list has a fluent scroll.

I have added the StrictMode in order to see performance tips and I can see:

> StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=139 ms:
>   android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=23
>   violation=2

I guess that Pixate is reading the css file for each item of the list and this does that the list has a bad performance.

Does someone have the same problem or know some related issue?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

My problem was that in the adapter I was using 2 types of rows so I was using bad the cache. This tutorial helped me a lot:
http://logc.at/2011/10/10/handling-listviews-with-multiple-row-types/

The problem was mine so +1 To Pixate

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How are you applying this to the `ListView`? In your `Adapter`? Please show some code. That might help explain why you're getting this issue.

Comment: Pixate is proxying the list adapter to add some unique tagging for the views that are getting recycled as you scroll. So, as @Rarw have mentioned, the content of your CSS, how you style the cells, and your own adapter, may all effect the performance.

Comment: @sgibly that's exactly my concern. `ListView` implements a number of internal optimizations such as view recycling where the adapter will only inflate the number of views required to fill the screen and then reuse them as you scroll. If you're forcing it to create new views for each list item that could be one reason why the performance is bad. I'd need to see code to say for sure.

Comment: Thanks @Rarw. Your comments make me review my code again hehe. I edit my question with my problem solved.

Comment: Thanks @sgibly. Your comments make me review my code again hehe. I edit my question with my problem solved.